# Rails: how to test if parent has grandchildren present in child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I (want to) have a method in a parent model (`groups`) to check if a child (`subjects`) has children (`goals`)

## `groups.rb`:

```
def has_goals?
  @answer = []
  subjects = self.subjects
  subjects.each do |subject|
    if subject.try(:goals).present?
      @answer << true
    else
      @answer << false
    end  
  end  
  if @answer.include?("true")
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I would use this like so -

```
if group.has_goals?
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

at the moment it's not working as it's returning `false` for everything - whether the `subject` has `goals` or not.  Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if any of the `subjects` has at least a `goal` (`subjects.goals` should return `[]` if the subject has no goals):

```
def has_goals
  subjects.any? { |subject| subject.goals.present? }
end
```

Enumerable#any? reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F